# Reuse part of Drools `when` statement

Tags: java, drools

I have bulk of Drools rules with the similar `when` parts. E.g.

```
rule "Rule 1"
    when
        trn: TransactionEvent()

        // some `trn` related statements

        not ConfirmEvent (
            processMessageId == trn.groupId )
    then
        // some actions
end

rule "Rule 2"
    when
        trn: TransactionEvent()

        // some other `trn` related statements

        not ConfirmEvent (
            processMessageId == trn.groupId )
    then
        // some other actions
end
```

Is it possible to define one time this statement

```
not ConfirmEvent (
    processMessageId == trn.groupId )
```

and reuse somehow where needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approach ideas:

1. Use the rule "extends" keyword with each rule to extend a base rule containing the shared when statements.
2. Create a rule with the shared when statements that infers a fact ("extract rule").  Use that fact in the when conditions of the rules needing the shared conditions.  This option is typically my preferred approach as it defines a "concept" (a named fact) for those conditions and evaluates only once vs each rule.

   Rule example for #2:

   ```
   rule "Transaction situation exists"
       when
           trn: TransactionEvent()

           // some `trn` related statements

           $optionalData : // bind as wanted

           not ConfirmEvent (
               processMessageId == trn.groupId )
       then
           InferredFact $inferredFact = new InferredFact($optionalData);
           insertLogical($inferredFact);
   end

   rule "Rule 1"
       when
           InferredFact()
           AdditionalCondition()
       then
           // some actions
   end

   rule "Rule 2"
       when
           InferredFact()
           OtherCondition()
       then
           // some other actions
   end
   ```

Comment: Could you, pls, explain the second idea and illustrate it with some peace of code (rules)?

Comment: Added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should be obvious that the `not` CE is not valid on its own since it refers to some `trn`. But since the `trn` is introduced by another CE, you can use extends based on their combination:

```
rule "Commont TE + not CE"
when
    trn: TransactionEvent()
    not ConfirmEvent ( processMessageId == trn.groupId )
then
end

rule "Rule 1" extends "Commont TE + not CE"
when
    // some `trn` related statements
then
    //...
end
```

and so on, for `Rule 2` and others.